# passing input text from view to contoller with FacebookContext using Facebook app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, facebook, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to pass a input text from view to controller in Facebook birthday app:
link for app: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/aspnet-mvc-facebook-birthday-app

in HomeController

```
[FacebookAuthorize("email", "user_photos")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index(FacebookContext context)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = await context.Client.GetCurrentUserAsync<MyAppUser>();
            return View(user);
        }
        return View("Error");
    }

[HttpPost]
[FacebookAuthorize("email", "user_photos")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index(string txt,FacebookContext context)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = await context.Client.GetCurrentUserAsync<MyAppUser>();

// my code , I use txt here

            return View(user);
        }
        return View("Error");
    }
```

view:

```
@using facebookpostc.Models
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Facebook.Models
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Facebook
@model MyAppUser
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
<article id="content">
<div class="right">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "HomeController"))
{
<br />
<span>please input your text: </span>
<input type="text" id="txt" name="txt" />   
<input type="submit" />            
} 
</div>
</article>
```

but it is not passing text, I tried to pass text in many way but none of them passed text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read it from **FormCollection**:

```
[HttpPost]
[FacebookAuthorize("email", "user_photos")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index(FormCollection form,FacebookContext context)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            string temp = form["txt"].ToString();
            var user = await context.Client.GetCurrentUserAsync<MyAppUser>();

// my code , I use txt here

            return View(user);
        }
        return View("Error");
    }
```